# Inseparable field extensions of degree p and linear independence

Tags: co.combinatorics, linear-algebra, arithmetic-geometry, finite-fields, quadratic-forms

Let $F$ be a field of characteristic $p$; let $\alpha \in F$ such that $\alpha \neq \beta^p$ for any $\beta \in F$, and let $K := F(x)$ where $x=\sqrt[p]{\alpha}$.

Is it true that the elements $1,(x-1)^{p-1},(x^2-1)^{p-1},\dots,(x^{p-1}-1)^{p-1}$ are linearly independent over $F$?

Comment: Please write the nonstandard notation $F[x : x^p = \alpha]$ more clearly.  You didn't even define what $\alpha$ means. Presumably $\alpha$ is a nonzero element of $F$ that is not a $p$th power in $F$. If so, *say that*.  And write the field as $F(\sqrt[p]{\alpha})$ or as "$F(x)$ where $x^p = \alpha$.''

Comment: For $k \geq 1$, $(x^k - 1)^{p-1} = (x^k-1)^{p}/(x^k-1) = (\alpha^k-1)/(x^k-1)$ and $\alpha^k-1$ is in $F$ and is not 0 (because $\alpha^k = 1 \Rightarrow \alpha$ is algebraic over $\mathbf F_p$, but that would contradict the assumed inseparability of $K/F$), so the linear independence of that list over $F$ is equivalent to the linear independence of $1, 1/(x-1), 1/(x^2-1), \ldots, 1/(x^{p-1}-1)$. An $F$-linear relation among that list is reminiscent of partial fraction decompositions, and maybe you can find a contradiction from that point of view.